# jquery not calling php function

Tags: plugins, ajax

I just can't seem to get my jquery to call my php handler function in my plugin.
Please help. TQ

UPDATED : I updated the codes. It is working now.

My php file

```
// INIT
function nizam_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nizam_ajax', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/nizam_plugin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script('nizam_ajax', 'nizam_handler', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );    
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'nizam_scripts'); 


// SHORTCODE
function nizam_shortcode(){
    $html .= '<input size="10" type="text" class="ajax_bahagian" name="bahagian" value="100">';
    $html .= '<button class="btn_add" onclick="window.location.href = \'javascript:void(0)\';">Add</button>';                                  
    return $html;       
}      
add_shortcode( 'nizam_plugin', 'nizam_shortcode' );

// HANDLER     
function nizam_handler() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $bahagian  = $_REQUEST['bahagian']; 
        echo $bahagian;
    }  

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nizam_handler', 'nizam_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nizam_handler', 'nizam_handler' );
```

My jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    $('.btn_add').on('click', function(event) {
        var bahagian = $('.ajax_bahagian').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data: {
                'action'    : 'nizam_handler', 
                'bahagian'  : bahagian
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){ 
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });      

    });          


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logged in users, use:

- `wp_ajax_{$action}`

For logged out users, use:

- `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`

Your code is currently using `wp_ajax_{$action} -> wp_ajax_nizam_handler` which will restrict the request to logged in (authenticated users).

If you are logged out at the time of the request, you will never make it into your callback.

If you want to target logged out users add an action for the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` context.

#### Example:

```php
function wpse_356672_nizam_handler_handler() {

    wp_send_json_success( [
        'results'  => 'MY_VALUE',
        'custom_property'  => 'ANOTHER_VALUE',
        // etc...
    ] );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nizam_handler', 'wpse_356672_nizam_handler_handler' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nizam_handler', 'wpse_356672_nizam_handler_handler' );
```

NOTE: you can use both hooks simultaneously OR one or the other, depending on your use case.

TIP: instead of using `die` it is recommended that you use `wp_die` but even more so `wp_send_json_success`, `wp_send_json_error` or `wp_send_json`.

#### Recommended Reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax__requestaction/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

#### Aditional Reading (security):

- [AJAX Nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#nonce)
- [WordPress_Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)

Comment: Noted on the wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}

But my main issue is call from the jquery is not calling the php handler. Value from jquery is not passed to php. I might have missed something.

Comment: Do you end up in the `nizam_handler` function? If so, `var_dump( $_REQUEST );`. If not, are you sure you are logged in and have you tried the `nopriv` context simultaneously? What does `console.log(response);` say and do you see any errors or notices in Dev Tools?

Comment: Got an error
HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - https://www.pewarisan.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Yes, already add nopriv

Comment: @Enaizi the only time it throws a 400 from `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is if it cannot find the action `if ( ! has_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}" ) ) { ( '0', 400 ); }`. Where is your PHP file? How do you include it?

Comment: OK, got it to work. There were some typos.

Comment: Thought so... I tried issuing a bunch of requests myself. Glad you got it sorted.